# What can we say about the intersection of a clopen set and a connected set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

Let $X$ be a metric space and let $E \subseteq X$ be a clopen subset. let $A \subseteq X$ be a connected subset. What can be said about $A \cap E$ when $A \cap E \neq \varnothing$?

I believe that  $E \cap A$ is a clopen set under $A$ (what does that say about $E \cap A$ under $X$?), but I don't know mechanically how to prove this (e.g. prove that it contains its limit points and its complement also contains its limit points).

The explanation (attempt) that comes to mind is that an arbitrary limit point of $A \cap E$ under $A$ must be an element of $A$ (e.g. limit points of $A$, which might not be points of $A$, are not a part of the topological space $A \cap E$.). Thus $A \cap E$ is closed. Similarly, since $E^c$ is clopen, $A \cap E^c$ is closed, thus $A \cap E$ is clopen.

I still feel that I am waving my hand at a lot of detail and that I don't really understand it means for this to be true under $A$ versus under $X$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s true almost by definition that if $E$ is clopen in $X$, then $E\cap A$ is clopen in $A$. Let $\tau$ be the topology of $X$, and let $\tau_A$ be the topology of $A$. By definition $\tau_A=\{U\cap A:U\in\tau\}$. $E$ is clopen in $X$, so $E\in\tau$, and therefore $E\cap A\in\tau_A$, i.e., $E\cap A$ is open in $A$. $E$ is closed in $X$, so $X\setminus E\in\tau$, and therefore $A\setminus E=(X\setminus E)\cap A\in\tau_A$ as well. Thus, $E\cap A=A\setminus(A\setminus E)$ is closed in $A$ and therefore clopen in $A$.

Once that’s out of the way, you can concentrate on the real point of the question. $A$ is connected, so its only clopen subsets are $\varnothing$ and $A$ itself. Thus, if $E\cap A\ne\varnothing$, then ... ?

Comment: $A \subseteq E$, otherwise we would have $E \cap A$ and $E^c \cap A$, two proper clopen subsets of $A$?

Comment: @user2127595: Exactly right.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: @user2127595: You’re welcome!